# Grid background in Expandable ViewCell does not fully cover ViewCell on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create an expandable ListView, but I have a problem with the background color on iOS, as this will not fit the ViewCell.
It is working correctly on Android and UWP.

I have tried some different approaches.

The first approach is this

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="DEL" />
   <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start">
      <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Label LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding Description}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding ProjectReference}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
         </StackLayout>
         <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Amount}" />
         <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsMoreInfoAvailable}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChangeMoreInfoCommand}" />
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="More info" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MoreInfoIcon}" />
         </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ShowMoreInfo}" VerticalOptions="Start">
         <Label Text="{Binding Address}" />
      </StackLayout>
   </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

And another approach is this

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="DEL" />
   <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start">
         <Label LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding Description}" />
         <Label Text="{Binding ProjectReference}" />
         <Label Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Amount}" />
      <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsMoreInfoAvailable}">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChangeMoreInfoCommand}" />
         </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
         <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="More info" />
         <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MoreInfoIcon}" />
      </Grid>
   </Grid>
   <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{Binding ShowMoreInfo}" VerticalOptions="Start">
      <Label Text="{Binding Address}" />
   </StackLayout>
 </Grid>
```

And both approaches work on UWP and Android but neither of them work on iOS

The command consist of

```
ShowMoreInfo = !ShowMoreInfo;
MoreInfoIcon = ShowMoreInfo ? "-" : "+";
UpdateLayout?.Invoke();
```

Where the `UpdateLayout` action is only set on iOS and is set to `ForceUpdateSize`

The source code can be found on [WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/66a5838c5ac4c4e96fad120a79892f9520181029201901/87403f)

**EDIT**

I expect the layout to look like this, when I expand the ViewCell
[image: Correct layout]

But instead it looks like this, when I expand the ViewCell
[image: As it looks like]

The problem only occurs, when the ViewCell is expanded for the 1st time.

Comment: Can you attach images on how it is supposed to look like and how it is currently looking.

Comment: I have just attached the images